# Modal not hidden on ios - React Native

Tags: react-native, activity-indicator

I have a modal with a View and ActivityIndicator that I use to show the user something is loading. Here's the component:

```
const ActivityIndicatorView: React.FC<Props> = ({show}) => {
  return (
    <Modal animationType="fade" transparent={true} visible={show}>
      <View style={styles.centeredView}>
        <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} color={FOREGROUND_YELLOW} />
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

This has been working fine. But now I have a specific situation where the variable `show` is changed from true to false but the modal does not disappear. This only happens on iOS, it works as expected on Android.

Any clue why?

Comment: do you update the `show` variable via setState?

Comment: The variable is changed with mobx in another component (using `makeObservable`) @TommyLeong